# How can I use if statement after a CTE (SQL Server 2005)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, common-table-expression

Last night I was writing a simple T-SQL program something like this

```
DECLARE @ROLEID AS INT

SELECT @ROLEID = [ROLE ID] FROM TBLROLE

;WITH CTE
AS
( 
    SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE
)
IF (@ROLEID  = 1) 
BEGIN
      //SOMECODE
END
ELSE IF(@ROLEID  = 2) 
BEGIN
      //SOMECODE
END
ELSE
BEGIN 
      //SOMECODE
END
```

I found after compilation that it is throwing error something like "Incorrect statement near if"

What is wrong?

However, I did that by using some other way. But I wanted to know why it did not work!

Comment: What does //SOMECODE do in each case? If they are, for example, UPDATE statements all targeting the same table then you may be able omit the procedural code using the @ROLEID variable and instead write a single UPDATE using a set-based approach.

Comment: Actually I am selecting the records like select * from tblname. not any dml operations

Comment: use temp tables instead

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[Common table expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) are defined within the context of a single statement:

```
WITH cte_name AS (
  <cte definition>)
<statement that uses cte>;
```

So you can do something like:

```
WITH CTE
AS
( 
    SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE
)
SELECT * FROM CTE;
```

or

```
WITH CTE
AS
( 
    SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE
)
UPDATE CTE 
SET somefield = somevalue
WHERE id = somekey;
```

> A CTE must be followed by a single
>   SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, MERGE, or
>   DELETE statement that references some
>   or all the CTE columns. A CTE can also
>   be specified in a CREATE VIEW
>   statement as part of the defining
>   SELECT statement of the view

Comment: You can use SELECT * INTO #TempTable FROM CTE immediately after WITH CTE AS ( )  and then use IF  .... ELSE  .... which can column values from #TempTable for conditions in IF , ELSE.

Answer (score 14):

A little late but I can't be the only one bumping into this.

A solution could be to create a temporary table like this:

```
-- If previous run of this query fails, the temp table will be deleted.
-- Selecting into creates the temp table which fails if it already exists
IF EXISTS(SELECT [name] FROM tempdb.sys.tables WHERE [name] like '#dtBalansOpgesteldGefilterd%') BEGIN
   DROP TABLE #temp
END;

;WITH CTE
AS
( 
    SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE
)

-- Followed by select statement as required
SELECT *
INTO #temp
FROM CTE

IF @awsome = 1
BEGIN
    SELECT 'WHATEVERYOUWANT' AS WhateverColumnNameYouWant, *
    FROM #temp
END
```

Comment: Wrapping the entire thing in `BEGIN TRANSACTION; CREATE TABLE #temp; [entire thing]; DROP TABLE #temp; COMMIT` was recommended to me over checking if the table exists and it worked a bit better as it removed a problem with special permissions needed to drop the temp table.

Comment: just to simplify if the temp table already exists 'If object_id('tempdb..#temp') is not null
 drop table #temp'

Answer (score 10):

The closest you'll get is using a UNION ALL to do a crude switched select:

```
DECLARE @ROLEID AS INT

SELECT @ROLEID = [ROLE ID] FROM TBLROLE

;WITH CTE
AS
( 
    SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE
)
SELECT
    --somecolumns
FROM
    CTE
    --other stuff too
WHERE
    @ROLEID = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT
    --somecolumns
FROM
    CTE
    --other stuff too
WHERE
    @ROLEID = 2
UNION ALL
SELECT
    --somecolumns
FROM
    CTE
    --other stuff too
WHERE
    @ROLEID = 3
...
UNION ALL
SELECT
    --somecolumns
FROM
    CTE
    --other stuff too
WHERE
    @ROLEID = n
```

Comment: For this case the columns need to be same. I have a case where columns are different. Still finding a solution

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the CTE in the IF. It worked for me.

```
IF @awsome = 1
BEGIN
;WITH CTE
AS
( 
    SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE
)
    SELECT 'WHATEVERYOUWANT' FROM CTE
END
ELSE IF @awesome = 2
BEGIN
;WITH CTE2
AS
( 
    SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE
)
    SELECT 'WHATEVERYOUWANT' FROM CTE2
END
```

Comment: If the CTE (or CTEs) are complex, this results in a lot of duplicated SQL. Then you have to fix any issues in both branches of the IF.