# SQL Server : reuse (the result of) a statement without CTE (Common Table Expression) or temporary table

Tags: sql-server, code-reuse

I want to reuse the result table of a SQL statement in an `IF` clause.

```
If (SELECT Count(*) FROM TABLE = 0)
...
ELSE
SELECT COLUMN FROM TABLE
```

A CTE is for a single expression only and an IF-statement is not allowed.

Here

[How can I use if statement after a CTE (SQL Server 2005)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558091/how-can-i-use-if-statement-after-a-cte-sql-server-2005)

is a workaround using temporary tables.

For security reasons I am not allowed to use `DROP` commands, so I cannot `DROP` the temporary table in order to allow more than 1 execution of the statement (Select into fails, if the temporary table already exists).

I tried to (mis)use CASE for this:

```
WITH SET AS (..)
SELECT
WHEN CASE ((SELECT Count(*) FROM SET) = 0)
...
ELSE
SELECT COLUMN FROM SET
```

but this works only if the result is a single value (A column with only a single entry) and does not return the column name.

Is it really that hard to simply reuse the result of a statement?!

Comment: well, if you use a #temp table in a stored procedure, the temp table gets automatically dropped when execution is done. you could use a @table variable instead, which will let you run multiple times without a drop. The other work around is to use the temp table, but then open up a new execution window each time, because that "drops" the table automatically. It's a bit ridiculous you can't put a drop in for a temp table, because there is no security risk in that.

Comment: Your problem is that you can't "select into" a temp table more than once because that syntax is trying to both "select into" and "create" the table all in one statement.  The second time it runs it can't create the same table. But you can define the temp table first and then insert items into the table as many times as you need to.  So you could define table first before your select statements and then use "insert into" temp table instead of "select into".  Once the temp table falls out of scope, it will be automatically dropped.

Comment: @Jeremy Why don't you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @ralph based on the question the OP states: "Select into fails if the temporary table exists" is an indication that the OP is using that syntax.  Otherwise "insert into" syntax would not fail.  Thus the assumption that select into is being used as stated in question.

Comment: What version of sql are you working with? what about a table variable?

Comment: @cnaegle: I know "Insert into" only with explicit values written in the statement (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) - Is it possible to use insert into for the values returned by a query?

@ Zohar Peled: 2008.

@ all I followed the suggestion to use a table variable.